# Networkx: how to select all the edges having a given key value?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

With networkx and for a multigraph, how to select all the edges having a given key value?

For example how can I select all the edges with `key==2`?

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.MultiDiGraph()

G.add_edge(1,2,key=0)
G.add_edge(1,2,key=1)
G.add_edge(1,2,key=2)
G.add_edge(2,3,key=0)
G.add_edge(2,3,key=1)
G.add_edge(2,3,key=2)
G.add_edge(3,4,key=0)
G.add_edge(3,5,key=1)
G.add_edge(3,6,key=2)

#For Example:
#edges with key=2
#(1,2)
#(2,3)
#(3,6)
#Nodes linked to edges with key=2
#1,2,3,6
```

After searching I am using solution proposed by avaris at topic:
[What is the correct graph data structure to differentiate between nodes with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828349/what-is-the-correct-graph-data-structure-to-differentiate-between-nodes-with-the/8830257#8830257)

But I guess that there might be a more direct solution.

Sorry for not adding the code example on my firs entry.

Comment: Could you add some code that creates a simple multigraph? And then give a very concrete example of what you want to select?

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I add a simple example.

Comment: Is your application also a bipartite graph?

Comment: At my application the graph is not completely bipartite. I have two main big grapths. One of them is bipartite (in fact it is really tripartite if this concept exitis) but the other is not. The triparite graph is used to complete the edge information of the other main graph. Apart from filtering it would be very useful for me to draw the graph but due to it is MultiDiGraph I should used graphviz. Unfortunately I am newby wiht python and I found very complex to install it. So now I am focusing on completing and sorting information on the graph.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this:

```py
print("All edges with key 2:",
      [(i, j, k)   for i, j, k in G.edges if k == 2])
print("All nodes connected to edges with key 2:",
      set( [n for i, j, k in G.edges if k == 2  for n in [i, j]] ))
```

Output:

```
All edges with key 2: [(1, 2, 2), (2, 3, 2), (3, 6, 2)]
All nodes connected to edges with key 2: {1, 2, 3, 6}
```

Comment: If you're graph is huge, you might reconsider using a networkx graph to represent your data. Or represent it both in something like a pandas dataframe and only use networkx for specific graph operations.

Comment: Thank for the advise. I started modeling my problem with tables, then I moved to use set theory with matrix. And finally I discovered graph theory that fits really well with my problem. I rewrite the code with a reduction of 50%. I was wondering if it would be recommended to use graph for everything. With your advice I guess graph use must not be extensive. Which might be the criteria to choose between one or another?

Comment: My idea is that networkx is most useful for not too large graphs, especially when you want to visualize them.